# How to make Firebase Database Query to get some of the children using Swift 3?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

How can I make a Query in Firebase database to get some of the children in my console? For example, from the snapshot below, how can I make a query to get just the `Image`s where `Des: 11`.

[image: This is a snapshot for my console in firebase database]

I'm using this code:

```
   func loadData(){


    Ref=FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts")

    Handle = Ref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "11").observe(.childAdded ,with: { (snapshot) in

        if  let post = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

            let img = Posts()

            img.setValuesForKeys(post)

            self.myarray.append(img)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

    })

}
```

Comment: `ref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "Des").queryEqual(toValue: "11").observe(.childAdded ,with: { (snapshot) in
        if  let post = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            //....
        }
    })`

Comment: Thanks for help , but this error appears in debug (Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "Des" at /Posts to your security rules for better performance)

Comment: thats not an error .. it suggest you to change your rules for better performance .. but still your project works with this warning

Comment: Ok , but there is no thing to show when I run the app its appears empty.

Comment: Thank you El Capitain its worked now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As El Capitain said, you'll need to use this:

```
func loadData(){

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts")

    ref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "Des").queryEqual(toValue: "11").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in 
        if let post = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] { 
            // do stuff with 'post' here.

        } 
    })

}
```

Also, as he mentioned, you'll want to set your security rules to allow you to search by 'Des', or whatever other child node you'll be querying by. In addition, you'll need to set the rules to allow you read access to the query location:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",

    "Posts": {
      "$someID": {
        ".indexOn": ["Des"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, you're not going to get 'only the images' though, your query will return the entire node. In this case, the query above would return the rrrrrr node.

Comment: I do it like you answer but still when I run my project its appears empty and no thing to display .

Comment: Worked for me, thank you. I had been using this which returned all the data::

databaseRef.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {      snapshot in

But wanted to download if it met certain criteria and the code worked great

Comment: Very specifically, for me the change was minor. Use the .childAdded instead of .value which seems to return only the queried item that matches the criteria. It's subtle, at least it was to me.