# Implementing Username in Firebase Realtime Database (swift 4)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First of all, sorry for my bad English and asking a very basic question.

I'm very new in swift & iOS programming as well as Firebase Realtime Database.

How can I reference the username of a user to the post of the user?

I'm thinking the `userId` can function as sort of a key for refrencing.

[image: my JSON structure screenshot]

My end goal is just to get all the post (done) and have the username of who posted that.

I have worked with PHP and MySQL (never worked on JSON before) and usually achieve this with no problem, but I'm unsure on how to implement this one in Firebase, probably because I'm not very sure on the queries.

I have read the queries available for Firebase and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606963/how-to-make-firebase-database-query-to-get-some-of-the-children-using-swift-3)  but still not so sure as in my case it's a little bit different.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @Rohit i want to get the username of the poster.

Comment: You can simply store the username under the post. It is very common to duplicate data in nosql. I suggest you look up some posts about structuring nosql data for more information.

Comment: @AndréKool okay thanks! :)

Comment: While @AndréKool suggest is awesome, it leads to issues when, for example, a user name changes, it then needs to be changed at every location in the database. This will commonly happen when an email address is used and the user wants to keep their account but use a different email. Also, if you want to perform a query, you are querying by the username instead of a uid. Depending on your use case, go ahead and store the actual user name, but leveraging a uid reference is a safe alternative that does take a little more code but may provide additional flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller get your post from database by id:

```
class func getPosterId(post: Post, completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> Swift.Void) {

Database.database().reference().child("posts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                var posts = [Post]()

                let values = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
                let post = values[post.id]
                completion(post)
             }
        })
```

Then catch it in your ViewController from completion and get its `userId`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no joins in NoSQL. So you either have to perform another request or duplicate the data.

## Perform another request

Pretty straightforward, every time you an user's username, you request it. I don't advise it for information you'll always need and that "never" changes such as an username.

## Duplicate the data

You can either directly add the username with the `post` or use a Cloud Function db trigger to automatically duplicate the data you need. Advised in the case of username, but can be tricky in the case of variable information.